# Hard disk help required

Tags: hard-disk

I have an old desktop which do not have a harddisk. It has Lian Feng 2651 30awg cable attached to motherboard. Can someone suggest which harddisk should I buy for it?
I live in India so an Indian reference (website, shop, etc) would be really helpful.

[image]

Comment: As @Mark stated in his answer, you need an IDE or PATA drive which are now only available in the used market.  You might have a better question asking for a recommendation on a used PCI to SATA adapter so you can use the newer drives.

Comment: [Cross-site dupe](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9311/hard-disk-help-required)

Answer (score 2):

It is not a "Lian Feng 2651 30awg" cable, it is an ordinary [PATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) cable.

They've came out in multiple versions, floppies and very early IDE hard disks had a shorter one. But, on your photo it is visible that you have the older ones (since around 20 years). These had 40, or more later 80 wires. These are interchangeable, however using a later, 80-wire capable PATA hard disk with a 40-wire cable will be slower. The photo shows a 40-wire cable.

Beware, some floppy cables and SCSI cables look very similarly, but the count of the wires are different on them. If you want to make it sure, simply count the wires on the cable.

Practically no PATA hard disk is manufactured any more. If it is, you can't pay its price due to the low production numbers.

Your options:

1. Find an old "PATA hard disk" on the ebay or in any old hardware store. Most likely it will be the cheapest.
2. You can use a [PATA-SATA converter](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=pata%20sata%20converter) to attach the current SATA hard disks to your PATA motherboard.
3. You can also insert a SATA hdd controller PCI card into your computer, also these are available from around $10. However, probably you won't be able to boot from these hard disks, as your BIOS won't see them (it is possible if the controller card explicitly supports it). In this case, you will need some more tricky solutions (network boot, or boot from usb, all of them might be problematic with an ancient bios).

Most likely, no shop on the next street will ever sell such things to you. Even that is very likely, that no seller will even understand, what do you want. But, you can buy them online.